# Binding height and width of border to half of its children at runtime in windows 8.1 app

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I have a user control which have elements like this

```
<UserControl
x:Class="App2.MyImageControl"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App2"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300"
d:DesignWidth="400">

<Grid x:Name="MyGrid" x:FieldModifier="public" ManipulationMode="None" Tapped="MyGrid_Tapped" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
    <Grid.RenderTransform>
        <CompositeTransform></CompositeTransform>
    </Grid.RenderTransform>
    <Border x:Name="MyBorder" x:FieldModifier="public" BorderThickness="1"  BorderBrush="Transparent" Width="auto" Height="auto">
        <Grid>
            <Image x:Name="MyImageO" x:FieldModifier="public" Source="" Width="auto" Height="auto" Stretch="Fill"></Image>

        </Grid>

    </Border>
</Grid>
```

I want to bind MyBorder width and height to half of MyImageO width and height at runtime.How do I achieve that .

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the [`MultiplyConverter`](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit/WinRTXamlToolkit.Shared/Converters/MultiplyConverter.cs) to convert a bound value to half of it, but `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` aren't bindable - they don't raise change notifications. Your best bet is to simply handle `SizeChanged` events and then set the dimensions of the border based on `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` of the image.